Why do Marie's teeth differ?
I saw this picture from the 1970 Disney animated movie The Aristocats (source: Alamy)

All the cats except for Marie (the female kitten) have regular teeth separated by normal cleavages, and the middle cleavage is exactly aligned with the nose line.
But in Marie's case we see her teeth with irregular cleavages (just like Tom Cruise's teeth!)
Of course, you should zoom in. From a far her teeth looks like a Rabbit's or rat's!
Are there any explanations by the team? Was it intentional or just a mistake?
